# How to add additional rasters to a for loop that can be combined into one complete dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, geospatial, raster, projection

I have a raster depicting global land type projections by colour (1-6) for 2050. I have cropped this to a polygon dataset of global seagrass distribution(cmu). I have run a for loop to calculate area of each land type (1.water, 2.forest, 3.urban, 4.barren, 5.cropland, 6.grassland) present on the seagrass polygons. How can I add my additional global land type rasters (e.g. for 2060, 2070, 2100) to my df.area dataframe so I can then analyse/graph how the land cover types change over time? (NB. This code is filtered for just australia as global one takes ages and i wanted to test workflow)

```
##CALCULATE AREA OF RASTER CLASSES###
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
cmu <- st_read('units-attributes-wgs84L2.gpkg')
land <- rast('7landtypes/SSP1_RCP19/global_SSP1_RCP19_2050.tif')
plot(land)

cmu2 <- filter(cmu, TERRITORY1 == 'Australia') %>% st_transform("+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

land.sub <- crop(land, vect(cmu2))

tmp <- list() # tmp object for storing results of loop as a list

system.time(
  for(i in 1:nrow(cmu2)){#loop through cmus and calculate area of diff. land classes
    s <- cmu2[i,] # subset a polygon from the cmu dataset
    rs <- crop(land.sub, vect(s), mask = TRUE)
    if(is.na(minmax(rs)[2]) == FALSE){
      tmp[[i]] <- data.frame(class = unname(values(rs)),
                             area_ha = unname(values(cellSize(rs, unit="ha")))) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(class)) %>% 
        group_by(class) %>% 
        summarise(area_ha = sum(area_ha, na.rm = T)) %>% 
        mutate(unit_ID = st_drop_geometry(s)[,1],
               raster = names (rs))
    }else{
      next
    } 
  } 
)

df.area <- do.call(rbind, tmp)

head(df.area)
# save
write.csv(df.area, 'land-class-area-cmu-2050.csv', row.names = F)
```

Comment: i am not too sure what your goal is. can you show us some expected output (on a very small scale)?. also i have a few questions regarding your sample code: 1) why does your `if-condition` use `is.na(...) ==  FALSE` instead of `!is.na(...)` as you did in your `filter` statement?, 2) why use `1:nrow()` instead of `seq_row()` or similar?, 3) why use `crop` (raster) instead of `st_crop`?

Comment: please provide a minimal (do not use `library(tidyverse)`) and a *self-contained* example, That is include some example data; just like you see in the help files that come with R and in most Q & A about *R* on this site. Have a look at ?terra::levels to see how to make a small categorical raster.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to answer a question like this but you probably could do this as I show below.

Example data

```
library(terra)
cmu <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
land <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
```

Solution

```
area <- cellSize(land)
zones <- rasterize(cmu, area, "ID_2")
z <- zonal(area, zones, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```